# Bootstrap Views Grid Unable to specify Medium and Small device classes

Tags: 7, views

I am currently using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap and successfully created a Bootstrap Grid

For each grid item I get the following output as the root most div tag

```
<div class="col col-lg-4">
```

But I need to add more class names as follows

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
```

is there a facility to provide additional classes which needs to be added in the root component of each rendered view content?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some months ago. It seems Bootstrap Views allows this possibility, but only in the `dev` release, not in the latest stable release.

In order to do what I wanted in the stable release of the module, I ended up with the following solution:

```
/**
 * Implements preprocess_views_view__VIEW().
 */
function scicnet_preprocess_views_view__MY_VIEW(&$vars) {
  $display_id = $vars['display_id'];
  switch ($display_id) {
    case 'MY_DISPLAY':
      $vars['rows'] = str_replace('col-lg-4', 'col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12', $vars['rows']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, I admit, but it does the job...